# Iterating an object from external api

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am a beginner to Javascript and I wanted to make an application that shows results from an external API. I tried the code below and I always get error in console telling that forEach is not a function. I understand that I receive the data in object. I tried with map() and for iteraton, but nothing. Any help would be appriecated.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Mtg);

function Mtg() {
  fetch("https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((cards) => {
     
      let output = "";
      
      cards.forEach((key,value) => {
       
        output += `
          <div>${card.name}</div>
          <div>${card.imageUrl}</div>
        `
      });

      console.log(cards);

      document.getElementById("mtgCardsContainer").innerHTML = output;
    });
}
```

Comment: `cards` is probably not an array. Given that it looks like you're trying to pull key/value pairs out of it, you already know this and are using `forEach` wrong. Review what [methods are available to objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). You probably want [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cards as an object, and what you need is inside this object. Also output part is wrong as well, you have no `card` variable. So,

```js
function Mtg() {
  fetch("https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(({cards}) => { // destruct cards from object
     
      let output = "";
      
      cards.forEach((card) => {
       
        output += `
          <div>${card.name}</div>
          <div>${card.imageUrl}</div>
        `
      });

      document.getElementById("mtgCardsContainer").innerHTML = output;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, you are just slightly off with targeting the correct part of the response.....

When you make the fetch request, you are returning a JSON object.
You have chosen to name that object cards.

In this case, the JSON object is returning an object you have named 'cards' which itself contains an array also called cards, so in order to access that array you need to target the following:

```
cards.cards.forEach((item, index) => {
 console.log(item)
});
```

To make your code more readable and less confusing, you may wish to change the name of the cards variable relating to the returned JSON object....

```
.then((data) => {
     
  let output = "";
      
  data.cards.forEach((item, index) => {
   console.log(item)
    output += `
      <div>${item.name}</div>
      <div>${item.imageUrl}</div>
    `
  });
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some refactoring and add some comments. Good luck:

```js
/**
 *
 * @param card {Object}
 * @returns {string} as HTML
 */
const cardTemplateHTML = (card) => {

  return `
    <div>${card.name}</div>
    <div>${card.imageUrl}</div>
  `
};

/**
 *
 * @param cards {Object}
 */
const renderCards = ({cards}) => { /*
      note: your currently inject the object data that contains cards. So by using the modern syntax { cards }
      you don't have to write 'const {cards} = data' or 'const cards = data.cards'
      */
  const mtgCardsContainer = document.getElementById("mtgCardsContainer");

  //generate HTML
  const cardsHTML = cards.map(card => {
    //generete the HTML for every entry
    return cardTemplateHTML(card)
  })
      //merge the list together into one string
      .join('');

  //update DOM
  mtgCardsContainer.innerHTML = cardsHTML;
}

const Mtg = () => {
  // make fetch promise
  fetch("https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards")
      //fetch result, returns new promise
      .then((res) => res.json())
      //fetch result, returns the rendered json data
      .then((data) => renderCards(data)); /* return data example: data = { cards } */
}

//Load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Mtg);
```

```html
<div id="mtgCardsContainer">

</div>
```